# Масштабирование ImageView под разные экраны

Tags: android, xml, android-imageview, android-xml

Здравствуйте.

Подскажите как сделать масштабирование imageView под разные экраны
Есть картинка(imageView) поверх которой размещены еще две(imageMenu1 и imageMenu2). Они размещены посередине imageView. Для 5 дюймового экрана все нормально. Но при выборе 7 или 6 дюймового экрана imageView маштабируется а imageMenu1 и imageMenu2 нет и смещаются с центра вверх и сторону.
XML :

```
 <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/RelatiMain"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/imageView"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:layout_marginTop="100dp"
                    app:srcCompat="@drawable/iphone_samsung_full_reflection"                 
                    android:contentDescription=""
                    tools:ignore="ContentDescription" />

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/imageMenu1"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    app:srcCompat="@drawable/menu1x150"                   
                    tools:ignore="ContentDescription"
                    android:layout_marginTop="200dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                    />             

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/imageMenu2"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    app:srcCompat="@drawable/menu2x150"                    
                    tools:ignore="ContentDescription"
                    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="190dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="200dp"/>

 </RelativeLayout>
```

Загрузил фото как выглядит нормально на 5 дюймовом экране
[image: Нормальный вид на 5 дюймовом экране]

При изменении на 7 или 6 дюймовый задняя картинка увеличивается, а стрелки (imageMenu1 и imageMenu2) остаются маленькими и смещаются с центра в правый верхний угол. Как сделать чтобы такая картинка была всегда на всех экранах?

Comment: Покажите картинку как вам надо расположить элементы. Не очень понятно ваше описание.

Comment: #Nikotin N добавил фото. Как выглядит нормально и описал что происходит при изменении экрана.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема в том, что ваша верстка описана в абсолютных значениях, и она будет выглядеть нормально только на том размере экрана, на котором вы ее описывали. Для более универсальной верстки нужно использовать относительные величины. Например, я бы сделал так:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ivMain"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/ivMain"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/ivMain"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/ivMain"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/ivMain"
        android:gravity="center">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginRight="16dp"/>

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp" />

    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: а imageview обязательно в LinerLayout помещать? Просто я хотел потом добавить на стрелки textView. Универсальная верстка заключается в помещение view в контейнеры(layout)? А можно как то получить коэффициент на который увеличивается разрешения\ диагональ и потом подставлять произведение коэффициента на изначальную длину в xml? Может быть есть статья по универсальной верстке для андроид, чтобы получить основы и  войти в курс дела ?

Comment: можно так же попробовать сделать разные макеты для разных размеров экранов и поместить их в разные папки: res/layout/my_layout.xml // layout for normal screen size ("default")
res/layout-small/my_layout.xml // layout for small screen size
res/layout-large/my_layout.xml // layout for large screen size
res/layout-xlarge/my_layout.xml // layout for extra large screen size
res/layout-xlarge-land/my_layout.xml // layout for extra large in landscape orientation